# Realizar busca em largura

Tags: c, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou com um trabalho para fazer e estou batendo muito a cabeça para entender como irei fazer o mesmo.
Eu devo realizar uma busca em largura com base em um *.txt*. A professora enviou parte do código (eu estou fazendo apenas a `main`), já consegui realizar a leitura do arquivo, mas não estou sabendo como fazer para alimentar o grafo e começar a busca em largura com base nos valores.

O arquivo *txt* vem dessa forma:

```
7 8

1 2 1

1 3 1

2 4 1

3 4 1

4 5 1

4 6 1

5 7 1

6 7 1
```

A primeira linha é a quantidade de vértices e quantidade de arestas.
Da segunda linha pra baixo são o vértice de origem, vértice alvo e peso (nesta ordem). Estou agarrado no `InsereAresta` na `main` (que é onde acredito que devo começar para montar o grafo).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNUMVERTICES 100
#define MAXNUMARESTAS 4500
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

typedef int TipoValorVertice;
typedef int TipoPeso;

typedef struct TipoItem
{
    TipoValorVertice Vertice ;
    TipoPeso Peso;
} TipoItem;

typedef struct TipoCelula *TipoApontador;

struct TipoCelula
{
    TipoItem Item;
    TipoApontador Prox;
} TipoCelula;

typedef struct TipoLista
{
    TipoApontador Primeiro , Ultimo;
} TipoLista;

typedef struct TipoGrafo
{
    TipoLista Adj[MAXNUMVERTICES + 1];
    TipoValorVertice NumVertices;
    short NumArestas;
} TipoGrafo;

void FLVazia(TipoLista *Lista)
{
    Lista->Primeiro = (TipoApontador) malloc(sizeof(TipoCelula ));
    Lista->Ultimo = Lista->Primeiro ;
    Lista->Primeiro->Prox = NULL;
}

void FGVazio(TipoGrafo *Grafo)
{
    long i ;
    for ( i = 0; i < Grafo->NumVertices; i ++)
        FLVazia(&Grafo->Adj[ i ] ) ;
}

void Insere(TipoItem x, TipoLista *Lista)
{
    Lista->Ultimo->Prox = (TipoApontador) malloc(sizeof(TipoCelula ));
    Lista->Ultimo = Lista->Ultimo->Prox;
    Lista->Ultimo->Item = x;
    Lista->Ultimo->Prox = NULL;
}

void InsereAresta(TipoValorVertice *V1, TipoValorVertice *V2, TipoPeso
                  *Peso, TipoGrafo *Grafo)
{
    TipoItem x;
    x.Vertice = *V2;
    x.Peso = *Peso;
    Insere(x, &Grafo->Adj[*V1] ) ;
}

short ExisteAresta(TipoValorVertice Vertice1 ,TipoValorVertice Vertice2 ,
                   TipoGrafo *Grafo)
{
    TipoApontador Aux;
    short EncontrouAresta = FALSE;
    Aux = Grafo->Adj[Vertice1 ] . Primeiro->Prox;

    while (Aux != NULL && EncontrouAresta == FALSE)
    {
        if ( Vertice2 == Aux->Item. Vertice ) EncontrouAresta = TRUE;
        Aux = Aux->Prox;
    }
    return EncontrouAresta;
}

short ListaAdjVazia(TipoValorVertice *Vertice , TipoGrafo *Grafo)
{
    return (Grafo->Adj[*Vertice ] . Primeiro == Grafo->Adj[*Vertice ] . Ultimo);
}

TipoApontador PrimeiroListaAdj(TipoValorVertice *Vertice , TipoGrafo *Grafo)
{
    return (Grafo ->Adj[*Vertice ] . Primeiro->Prox) ;
}

void ProxAdj(TipoValorVertice *Vertice , TipoGrafo *Grafo, TipoValorVertice *Adj , TipoPeso
             *Peso, TipoApontador *Prox, short *FimListaAdj)
{
    *Adj = (*Prox)->Item. Vertice ;
    *Peso = (*Prox)->Item.Peso;
    *Prox = (*Prox)->Prox;

    if (*Prox == NULL)
        *FimListaAdj = TRUE;
}

int Vazia(TipoLista Lista)
{
    return ( Lista.Primeiro == Lista.Ultimo ) ;
}

void Retira(TipoApontador p, TipoLista *Lista , TipoItem *Item)
{
    TipoApontador q;
    if (Vazia(*Lista ) || p == NULL || p->Prox == NULL)
    {
        printf ( " Erro : Lista vazia ou posicao nao existe \n" );
        return;
    }

    q = p->Prox;
    *Item = q->Item ;
    p->Prox = q->Prox;

    if (p->Prox == NULL)
        Lista->Ultimo = p;
    free(q);
}

void RetiraAresta(TipoValorVertice *V1, TipoValorVertice *V2, TipoPeso *Peso, TipoGrafo *Grafo)
{
    TipoApontador AuxAnterior , Aux;
    short EncontrouAresta = FALSE;
    TipoItem x;
    AuxAnterior = Grafo->Adj[*V1] . Primeiro;
    Aux = Grafo->Adj[*V1] . Primeiro->Prox;
    while (Aux != NULL && EncontrouAresta == FALSE)
    {
        if (*V2 == Aux->Item. Vertice)
        {
            Retira(AuxAnterior, &Grafo->Adj[*V1] , &x);
            Grafo->NumArestas--;
            EncontrouAresta = TRUE;
        }
        AuxAnterior = Aux;
        Aux = Aux->Prox;
    }
}

void LiberaGrafo(TipoGrafo *Grafo)
{
    TipoApontador AuxAnterior , Aux;
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < Grafo->NumVertices; i++)
    {
        Aux = Grafo->Adj[ i ].Primeiro->Prox;
        free(Grafo->Adj[ i ].Primeiro ) ;

        Grafo->Adj[ i ].Primeiro=NULL;
        while (Aux != NULL)
        {
            AuxAnterior = Aux;
            Aux = Aux->Prox;
            free(AuxAnterior);
        }
    }
    Grafo->NumVertices = 0;
}

void ImprimeGrafo(TipoGrafo *Grafo)
{
    int i ;
    TipoApontador Aux;
    for ( i = 0; i < Grafo->NumVertices; i++)
    {
        printf ( "Vertice%2d: " , i );
        if ( !Vazia(Grafo->Adj[ i ]))
        {
            Aux = Grafo->Adj[ i ] . Primeiro->Prox;
            while (Aux != NULL)
            {
                printf ( "%3d (%d) " , Aux->Item. Vertice , Aux->Item.Peso);
                Aux = Aux->Prox;
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main()
{
    int qtdVertices = 0, qtdArestas = 0;

    char line[1024];
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\ep1_teste1.txt","r");

    //Verifica se o arquivo não foi aberto.
    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int primeiraLinha = 1;

    //Lê cada linha e imprimi os valores de cada uma.
    while( fgets(line,1024,fp) )
    {
        printf("%s\n",line);

        if(primeiraLinha == 1)
        {
            char* variaveis = strtok(line, " ");
            while(variaveis != NULL)
            {
                if(qtdVertices == 0)
                    qtdVertices = atoi(variaveis);
                else
                    qtdArestas = atoi(variaveis);

                variaveis = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }

            primeiraLinha = 0;
        }
        //Segunda linha pra frente
        else
        {
            int contaVariavel = 0;
            int noPai = 0, noFilho = 0, peso = 0;

            TipoValorVertice *V1;
            TipoValorVertice *V2;
            TipoPeso *Peso;
            TipoGrafo *Grafo;

            char* variaveisSegundaLinha = strtok(line, " ");
            while(variaveisSegundaLinha != NULL)
            {
                if(contaVariavel == 0)
                {
                    noPai = atoi(variaveisSegundaLinha);
                }
                else if(contaVariavel == 1)
                {
                    noFilho = atoi(variaveisSegundaLinha);
                }
                else if(contaVariavel == 2)
                {
                    peso = atoi(variaveisSegundaLinha);
                }

                variaveisSegundaLinha = strtok(NULL, " ");
                contaVariavel++;
            }

            InsereAresta(V1, V2, Peso, Grafo); //Estou agarrado aqui
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: qual é o problema ?

Comment: Bom dia! Então, o meu problema inicial está sendo em pegar os dados do arquivo .txt. Eu preciso separar a primeira linha das outras, pois são dados diferentes. Na hora que monto meu grafo, a primeira linha continua vindo no     while( fgets(line,1024,fp) )

Comment: pelo que vejo no código não tem como a primeira linha continuar vindo no "fgets"...faça um teste e cole aqui as primeiras linhas que aparecem no terminal, com o resultado do "printf" que já está em seu programa

Comment: aliás, você deve deixar claro em sua pergunta quel é o problema, por isso esta explicação que você deu deve constar do texto da pergunta, senão ninguém vai conseguir adivinhar qual é o seu problema...